# How to avoid loop in *multiplication of multiple rows in data frame

Tags: r, loops, multiplication

This should be a simple one.
A is a data frame. I'm trying to compute A[1,]*A[2,]*A[3,]*** all the way down. Is there a way to do it without for loops? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use `apply` with the argument `MARGIN` is 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sapply` to take column-wise product

```
sapply(A, prod)

#  a   b   c 
#  6 120 504
```

or  `colProds` from `matrixStats`

```
matrixStats::colProds(as.matrix(A))
```

**data**

```
A <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6, c = 7:9)
```

Answer (score 3):

First let us create some data to work with:

```
set.seed(1)
A <- matrix(runif(1e8), ncol = 100, nrow = 10000)

# Same as A just a data.frame for sapply()
B <- as.data.frame(A)
```

`A` is a matrix (which is necessary for the matrix operations of `matrixStats::colProds` and `Rfast::colprods`). `B` is just the same matrix as a `data.frame` to use with sapply. The appropriateness of each method obviously depends on your use case.

@Ronak Shah proposed the following two methods

```
sapply(B, prod)
matrixStats::colProds(A)
```

@dc37 proposed this in the comment to your original post

```
apply(A, 2, prod)
```

A third solution would be to use the `Rfast` package.

```
Rfast::colprods(A)
```

We can benchmark each approach to see how they perform:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(sapply(B, prod),
            matrixStats::colProds(A),
            Rfast::colprods(A),
            apply(A, 2, prod))
```

We see that `apply()` and `matrixStats::colProds()` are slower than the solutions provided by `sapply()` and `Rfast::colprods()`. If you are only doing the operation once, it doesn't matter, but if you are doing it many times (e.g. inside a loop or a function to be optimized), then the time-differences might add up.

```
Unit: microseconds
                     expr    min      lq     mean  median     uq     max neval
          sapply(B, prod) 1199.3 1227.90 1329.564 1242.45 1273.9  4597.9   100
 matrixStats::colProds(A) 2445.5 2490.60 2967.945 2540.05 2740.4  8351.9   100
       Rfast::colprods(A)  723.4  738.45  854.042  750.25  767.7  4867.4   100
        apply(A, 2, prod) 4759.5 4828.50 5351.112 4872.15 5012.6 21006.0   100
```

Answer (score 2):

An option with `summarise_all` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
A %>%
   summarise_all(prod)
#  a   b   c
#1 6 120 504
```

#### data

```
A <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:6, c = 7:9)
```